# Como puedo mostrar estos datos usando datatables yajrabox.?

Tags: laravel, datatables

tengo esta duda de como poner el voton `ver resultados` en el datatable, la manera en la que hago las consultas es asi:

```
route::get('api/users', function(){
        return datatables()->eloquent(App\Usuario::query())->toJson();

});
```

y así tengo el script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#users').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: 'api/users',
            "columns":[
            { data: 'id_usu'},
            { data: 'nombre'},
            { data: 'email'},
            { data: 'edad'},
            { data: 'sexo'},
            { data: 'escolaridad'},
            { data: 'photo'},
            ]
        });
    } );
</script>
```

el boton que quisiera que aparezca es este

```
`<td><a href="{{ URL::action('UsuariosController@verRes', $usu->id_usu) }}"><button class="btn btn-success">Ver Detalles</button></a></td>`
```

He intentado con esto

```
$users = User::select(['id', 'name', 'email', 'password', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])->get();

        return Datatables::of($users)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
                return '<a href="#edit-'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>';
            })
            ->editColumn('id', 'ID: {{$id}}')
            ->removeColumn('password')
            ->make(true);
    }
```

y agregando esto en el script

```
 {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
```

Pero me da un error de que no encuestra el `action`.
Cabe resaltar que he cambiado las variables con tal de que cuadren con mi base de datos y mi modelo, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a mi pregunta,

tuve que agregar estoy en el controlador

```
$model = Usuario::query();
        // return datatables()->eloquent(Usuario::query())->toJson();
        return Datatables::eloquent($model)
        ->addColumn('action', function($user) {
            return '
<br><a href="' . route('VerResultado', $user->id_usu) . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Detalles">Ver Detalles</a>
                ';
        })
        ->toJson();
    }
```

y quedo de esta manera en el script de ajax

```
<script>
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#users').DataTable({
      "procesing": true,
      "serverside": true,
       responsive: true,
      "ajax": '{{ route('datatable/getdata') }}',
      "columns":[ 
        {data: 'id_usu', name: 'id_usu'}, 
        {data: 'nombre', name: 'nombre'},
        {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
        {data: 'edad', name: 'edad'},
        {data: 'sexo', name: 'sexo'},
        {data: 'escolaridad', name: 'escolaridad'},
        {data: 'photo', name: 'photo',
            render: function(data, type, full, meta){
              return "<img src=\"/imageuser/"+data+"\" height=\"60\"/>";
            }
          },
        {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
      ],
      order: [[1, 'asc']]
    });

} );
</script>
```